# Ubuntu Remote Login help

Tags: lightdm, remote

I'm trying to register a machine in the "Universal Client Configuration Service" so I can login remotely (via the login page for lightdm), however I'm not sure what to use in the "Server URL" field.

I'm guessing this connection will go trough my Ubuntu One account, so I'm not sure what to use here.

Steps I have done are:

1. On the login page, select remote login and click on setup
2. A temp login opens with firefox pointing to https://uccs.landscape.canonical.com/
3. Added name and protocol as rdp
4. Click on add remote desktop
5. Page refreshes back so I can add a server

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with Ubuntu One, it seems to be only a way to access computers that have RDP enabled already.

The "server URL" will be the DNS name  or IP address of your machine. If this machine is located behind a NAT router (e.g in your home network) you will need to tell the router to forward RDP packets to this machine and the public IP address of your router would be the "server URL".